# C# Как открыть дочернюю форму в родительской при нажатии на кнопку, расположенную на НЕ дочерней форме

Tags: c#

Как открыть дочернюю форму в родительской при нажатии на кнопку, расположенную на **НЕ** дочерней форме. Т.е. есть форма 1 с MDI контейнером, с  формы 1 открывается форма 2, которая не является дочерней форме 1, а с формы 2 нужно открыть форму 3, которая будет дочерней форме 1.

Comment: А как вы пробовали? И что не получилось?

Comment: я нашел пример как из родительской формы открыть дочернюю
Form1 newForm = new Form1(this);
newForm.MdiParent = this;
newForm.Show();
но не знаю как этот код адаптировать под описанный случай
P.S. программирование не мой профиль, но приходится

Comment: Используйте этот же код, только вместо `this` передавайте первую форму

Comment: тогда выдает ошибку MainForm" является "тип", но используется как "переменная"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы вторая форма могла установить родителя третьей, она должна иметь на него ссылку, давайте заведем для этого свойство:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form MainForm { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Теперь, при открывании этой формы из первой нужно дать знать, что первая является "главной":

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.MainForm = this; // Здесь
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Теперь, когда во второй форме есть ссылка на первую, мы можем установить ее в качестве родителя для третьей, добавьте в код Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form3 = new Form3();
    form3.MdiParent = MainForm;
    form3.Show();
}
```

Готово!

---

Если вторая форма является у вас чем-то вроде диалога создания нового документа, вы можете открывать третью форму прямо из первой после закрытия второй:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
    if (form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var form3 = new Form3();
        form3.MdiParent = this;
        form3.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, кажется все работает как надо!